# Gaussian envelope on the diagonal of a matrix

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I want to create a matrix that is: (1) a normally distributed complex matrix (2) will have a Gaussian envelope on the diagonal (A gaussian of some width `sigma` peaked at the diagonal terms and decays on the off diagonal terms).
The first part is quite simple using the `randn` command:

```
N=1000;
S = randn(N)+1i*randn(N);
```

However, I'm quite lost on how to apply the Gaussian envelope. Help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I basically want to give the diagonal a shape of a Gaussian (it's real valued). Say the Gaussian's peak value is 1, then I want 1 on the diagonal and dropping values of the Gaussian on the off-diagonal ones.

Comment: A possible implementation may be to reshape the matrix so the diagonal terms are in the centre columns of the matrix/array then apply the Gaussian function. Then reverse the reshaping. I'm not too familiar with dealing with complex numbers in this scenario.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Hi and thanks for the reply. The Gaussian on the diagonal elements I want is real valued. Just to clarify, let's say the peak value of the Gaussian envelope is 1, so I want 1 to be on all the diagonal elements and dropping values of the Gaussian on the off diagonal ones. Basically, I just want to give the diagonal of the matrix a shape of a Gaussian.

Comment: It seems to me that the two requirements (1: each entry should be normally distributed and 2: the diagonal should have a Gaussian shape) are incompatible

Comment: @LuisMendo Why so? I'm trying to add to that matrix something like this: https://ibb.co/4P1ZsMr

Comment: @FlyGuy that is exactly what I had imagined.  That is a tricky question because calculating the offset/distance from a diagonal can be difficult.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Well, it depends on what you mean by "normally distributed complex matrix". If you mean i.i.d samples I don't see how it can be done. If not, you need to specify the distribution, or even the joint distribution, of the matrix entries

Comment: @LuisMendo Very, very true.

Comment: I'll try being clearer: Suppose I am looking at a specific element in this matrix I'm interested in ("normally distributed complex matrix"), and I draw this matrix MANY times and look at the value of this specific element. Then, this specific element will have a normal distribution of the real and imaginary part. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think S is then called a circularly symmetric complex gaussian random variable. This is what I meant by the first condition. Hope it cleared things up.